# stop session from logging user out

Tags: php

I have some code that I added to try and prevent the user from auto logging out (session). - but it still logs the user after so long

What I want is for the user to be able to access multiple pages when logged in and not log them out if they go idle, hence why I put a large idle time - or in other words , stay logged in until they decide to click logout.

**login-page**

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['username']=time();
            // Redirect user to index.php
        header("Location: admin-index.php");
         }else{
            $_SESSION['incorrect'] = 'Incorrect email or password. Please try again.';
            header ("Location: admin-login.php?=incorrectlogin");
    }
}
```

**logged in index page**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$idletime=6000000;
if (time()-$_SESSION['username']>$idletime){
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
    header ("Location: admin-login.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['username']=time();
}
//on session creation
$_SESSION['username']=time();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
```

**second php page**

```
<?php
session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: admin-login.php");
exit(); }
?>
```

Comment: A 'trick' to keep users logged in, is make an ajax call, fire off that ajax call every x-number of minutes and in the ajax call just do a session_start(); This will keep users logged in unless the computer decides to go down or into sleep mode

Comment: @Naruto - thanks for suggestion, Is there some link to where I can see how to do that, I have never used Ajax

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221475/how-to-set-session-lifetime-as-infinite might be useful

Comment: Give me a few minutes and i'll post an example here

Comment: Add `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 6000000);` to override the default session time

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of handling this:

You could change the lifespan of the sessions on the servers itself or if you can't access the server settings, you could try overwriting it through code:

`ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 6000000);`

[session.gc_maxlifetime manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796492/retrieve-php-server-session-timeout)

If you are unable to change the lifespan of sessions on the server, you could use this small code 'trick', keep in minde that if the clients pc shuts down or goes into sleep mode, the sessions will also expire:

Basicly you create a php script containing:

`session_start();`

Second you just write some jquery with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // keep alive
    setTimeout(keepalive(),120000);

});

function keepalive() {
    $.get( "url/to/ajax.php", function( data ) { setTimeout(callserver,12000);  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick, http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#example-5997

Starting with `Php version 7.0` was added an option to prevent session expire. A time of 86400 means 1 days. You can adjust as you want.

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0') >= 0) {
    session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 86400,]);
  } else {
    session_start();
  }
}
```

You can put at the top of `Php` files or include a file with this code on your project.

Hope this help.